# actframework can't save in database using $.merge

Tags: actframework

i'am trying to read data from a form and save it to database.first i read entity from database and use `$.merge(formdata).filter("-id").to(entity)` .I print the value and it's changed successful.But when i  call dao.save it do nothing;

the action code below

```
    @PutAction("{id}")
    public void update(@DbBind("id") @NotNull Category cate,Category category, ActionContext context) {
        notFoundIfNull(cate);
        try {
            $.merge(category).filter("-id").to(cate);
            System.out.print("name is " + cate.getName());
           // cate.setName("test"); // success
            this.dao.save(cate);
//            redirect("/admin/categories");
        } catch (io.ebean.DataIntegrityException e) {
            context.flash().error(e.getMessage());
            render("edit", category);
        }
    }
```

dao.save successful when i call cate.setName("test");

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you submit a issue to https://github.com/actframework/actframework/issues

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by myself using the following code

```
    public void mergeTo(Base target){

        if(!this.getClass().isAssignableFrom(target.getClass())){
            return;
        }

        Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();

        for(Method fromMethod: methods){
            if(fromMethod.getDeclaringClass().equals(this.getClass())
                    && fromMethod.getName().startsWith("get")){

                String fromName = fromMethod.getName();
                String toName = fromName.replace("get", "set");

                try {
                    Method toMetod = target.getClass().getMethod(toName, fromMethod.getReturnType());
                    Object value = fromMethod.invoke(this, (Object[])null);
                    if(value != null){
                        toMetod.invoke(target, value);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```